# React-Router | How can I use the IndexRoute and Redirect together? version: 1.0.0-rc1

Tags: reactjs, react-router

As captioned, how can I use them together?

Like this:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path="/" component={Root}>
    <Route path='home' component={HomeContainer}></Route>
    <Route path='about' component={AboutContainer}></Route>

    <IndexRoute component={HomeContainer}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

What if I need the IndexRoute that serves '/' to redirect to '/home'?

I cannot find any clue in the document of react-router 1.0.0-rc1.

Thanks.

---

[Edit]

Just to elaborate:

In the above configuration, when '/' is accessed, the page will be rendered using the HomeContainer; the displayed content is exactly the same as when the '/home' is accessed.

The difference is the URL in the browser address bar: in the former case the URL is "/" and in the latter case the URL is "/home"

I would like the URLs to be the same.  So I want the "/" (IndexRoute) to directly redirect to the "/home".

Hopefully this clarifies what I need.

PS:
I can use a Dummy component that only do the redirect, to achieve the behavior:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path="/" component={Root}>
    <Route path='home' component={HomeContainer}></Route>
    <Route path='about' component={AboutContainer}></Route>

    <IndexRoute component={DummyComponent}/>  // which only does redirect
  </Route>
</Router>
```

and in the DummyComponent:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.history.pushState(null, `/home`, null);
},
```

but it seems a little bit workaround.

Comment: can you show some example urls? I find it difficult to understand the behaviour you're wanting.

Comment: Add some clarification in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

For me the best solution was to use the `onEnter` function. (Not sure how well this works on 1.x as I use this on 2.0).

```
<IndexRoute onEnter={(targetState, replace) => {replace('/home')}} />
```